# Code to open browser is opening an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

Trying to open the browser with `ACTION_VIEW` **intent** but an activity from `manifest` is opened instead.

Here is my code

```
    val url = "https://www.google.com"
    val query = Uri.encode(url, "UTF-8")
    val browserIntent = Intent(CATEGORY_BROWSABLE, Uri.parse(Uri.decode(query)))
    browserIntent.setAction(ACTION_VIEW)
    activity.startActivity(browserIntent)
```

Comment: Which activity? You should show the relevant part of the manifest.

Comment: Why do you first encode and then decode?

Comment: I just realised I had a deeplink with the domain of the url. This is was why it was starting the Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing this.

The reason for this behaviour was I had a deeplink with domain of the url parsed. This is why an Activity in the app is started.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above code will work fine but if you are facing problem then instead of decode and encode as they both will be same you can directly use like this

```
val bint = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://google.com"))
startActivity(bint)
```

Hope it helps!!